# How to make RelativeLayout transparent without affecting the components in it

Tags: android

I want to make this RelativeLayout shown in the red stroked picture transparent, but keep the two buttons visible.

Thank you.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_prev" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: remove the background ?

Comment: But it mess up the other componts, I'm only showing you, the button part only. There are a lot of other components above.

Comment: given the code you showed, this is the most reasonable solution.

Comment: So would the next and back button will appear on top of the listbox elements while scrolling? I want it like that.

Comment: that depends on the rest of your layout, which, incidentally, i have no knowledge of, therefore I cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background to transparent:

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

in your colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

The first two digits in the color indicate transparency: 00 is fully transparent, FF is fully visible.

Comment: there is already an @android:color/transparent, no need to define a new one.

Comment: It's good practice not to use colors (or other resources) from the android package. I something changes there, it could crash your app. While this is not very likely with the transparent color, this is why I explicitly defined it.

Comment: source for this assertion? (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#PlatformResources seems to say otherwise)

Comment: You are right. In a previous version of the documentation (on referencing drawables), it said this: *Warning: Because these resources can change between platform versions, you should not reference these icons using the Android platform resource IDs (i.e. menu icons under android.R.drawable).*

Comment: So what is your suggestion guys?

Comment: Both are fine. It is very unlikely that the transparent color will be removed at some point.